# How can I see the game on my glasses when pressing play in the editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr

How can I see the game on my glasses when pressing play in the editor?

I'm using GearVR. USB Cable is plugged to my headset.

Comment: Have you tried [Unity remote](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html)?

Comment: @Hellium I use Unity Remote 5. I open it up. Connect the Phone to my GearVR and it opens the oculus panel instead of staying in unity remote..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build and deploy the app on your phone and when it runs then mount it in headset. You can not use unity remote for VR apps. This is because GearVR headset takes priority when you mount the phone. VR apps which have GearVR sdk enabled should default "insert your phone in headset" when you run it. An app can either be VR or Non-VR and UnityRemote is Non-VR App. Can only be used as container for Non-VR games.

Comment: Wow. That's unfortunate. The Oculus DK2 has the feature of enabling to see the scene without deploying the proj right?

Comment: The Rift has no problems doing it, only the Gear VR does.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I see. Well, in the future I'll get the DK2

Comment: Umm, it is likely cheaper to get a CV1 nowadays and you can use it to preivew just as good as you can in the DK2

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Plus don't forget you can still deploy then remote debug with unity using [adb over wifi](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-adb/#mobile-android-debug-intro-section-3) And you can use [developer mode](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-troublesh-device-run-app-outside/) to to get it to show on the device when it is out of the headset and you have the usb plugged in

Comment: @ScottChamberlain After I enabled the Gear VR Service Developer mode, and deployed the proj from unity into my phone, the game now shows on the phone. But how can it be seen on my headset without me putting it inside the headset?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS click the first link i posted about adb over wifi, you can then tell unity to use that adb connection when debugging. See also https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AttachingMonoDevelopDebuggerToAnAndroidDevice.html

Comment: @ScottChamberlain This is brilliant. Thanks again Scott!